# How to start sh file using javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sh

I am trying to start a sh file with javascript code that is executed with a button click. Just as information what my sh file does, it packs an application into a docker file an pushes it to Amazon AWS EC2 Container registry. 
Currently I am starting the sh file with a java class what works great.
Java class code:

```
public class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {


    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash","-lc", "/Users/test/Desktop/tag_push_image_AWS.sh"});

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));


    System.out.println("OUTPUT:\n");
    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

I tried already many solutions form stackoverflow and other platforms but none of them worked form me.

Here is just one example what i tried

```
function ButtonStart(){
console.log('test1');

var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;

child = exec('/bin/bash','-lc', '/Users/test/Desktop/tag_push_image_AWS.sh',
        function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
         console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
child();


    console.log('Image pushed')

}
```

Comment: are you trying to achieve this in a browser or on server?

Comment: The html files that contains the button which starts everything is in the browser but the rest will be on the server.

Comment: You can't execute anything locally from within a browser, or no-one would ever go on the internet.  If, however, you want to click a button in the browser and execute something on the server (that does not run locally to the browser) then you just need to handle the button click event and execute a Url, that holds server-side code to execute the script.

Comment: @Archer Than you I know that but how can i try everything for the moment because currently my sh file is only locally.

Comment: assuming your server is running node, you can use something like shelljs on the server.

Comment: It will *only* run on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I will consider you want to run the script on the server-side (if you want to do it from the browser, I don't think it's a good idea - executing shell scripts [is not a thing you can do](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-javascript-cannot-do-2037666) with javascript in the client side).

Seeing your snippet of code in Java, I understood you want to use the button as a trigger to run the bash script. If that's the case, I believe you should dispatch a HTTP Request to your server when the button is clicked and then, on your backend will process it inside a route controller.

If you are using `nodejs` and `express`, a good approach is to use the native `child-process` module, as you already pointed out:

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');

app.get('/run-my-sh-script', (req, res) => {

  childProcess.exec(`/bin/sh PATH_TO_YOUR_SH_FILE`, (err, stdout) => {
    if (err) {
      // threat your error here
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      // this is your output
      console.log(stdout);
    }

  })

})
```

And in your HTML code there should have something like this:

```
<a href="/run-my-sh-script"><button>Click here to run the script</button></a>
```

Comment: Yes exactly that is what i mean thank you :) but if i try this i get an error message that require is not defined.